# Possible to combine formattable with kableextra row wise?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra, formattable

Looking at this [relevant](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/use_kableExtra_with_formattable.html) vignette:

With the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)

set.seed(1)
data.frame(letters = letters[1:5],
           foo = rnorm(5, 20),
           bar = rnorm(5, 20),
           baz = rnorm(5, 20),
           bash = rnorm(5, 20)) %>%
    mutate(foo = color_tile("pink", "lightblue")(foo)) %>%
    kable(escape = F) %>%
    kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>%
    column_spec(5, width = "3cm") %>%
    add_header_above(c(" ", "Hello" = 2, "World" = 2))
```

You produce something like this:

[image]

Ultimately I would like to use the `color_tile` function from `formattable` rowwise - in my own dataset I need to compare values rowwise, while maintaining the structure of the data frame. I've tried transposing the dataframe but it makes a mess of my code and data and I don't think that route is plausible.

Comment: Use `row_spec()` instead of `column_spec()` https://rdrr.io/cran/kableExtra/man/row_spec.html - can't say any more without seeing your data

Comment: @anotherfred I modified the sample dataframe to make it more similar to my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract rows in a loop and run `color_tile()` on them.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(letters = letters[1:5],
           foo = rnorm(5, 20),
           bar = rnorm(5, 20),
           baz = rnorm(5, 20),
           bash = rnorm(5, 20),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) df[i,] <- color_tile("pink", "lightblue")(df[i,])

df %>%
  kable(escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(5, width = "3cm") %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Hello" = 2, "World" = 2))
```